# Переносы строки в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли в базе данных хранить `<br>`, если да то как фильтровать текст но пропустить перенос строки `<br>`.

Как это правильно сделать ?

```
if(isset($_POST['sumbit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
       $text = $_POST['text'];
       $text_br = nl2br($text);
    $date_pub = time(); 

    $data = "INSERT INTO blog (id, name, text, data_pub) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$text_br', '$date_pub' ) ";    
}


<?php  if (mysql_query($data) == true):  ?> 
    <div class="result_edit">Информация успешно изменена !!</div >
<?php  else:  ?>
    <div class="result_eror">Увы, но информация не изменена !!</div >
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Как вы сохраняете текст в базу? Код в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: Извините может неправильно задал вопрос, я изменил вопрос и добавил код.

Comment: У вас в этом коде нет записи данных в базу.

Comment: @Visman: вроде добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Функции `mysql_*` устарели! Их использовать не следует. Используйте [функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) `mysqli_*` для работы с базой.
2. Все входящие от пользователя данные должны проверяться/обрабатываться. Иначе вас ждет [SQL-инъекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

   2.1 Ожидаемые целые числа приводите строго к целым числа так

   ```
   $number_int = (int)$_POST['number'];
   ```

   2.2 Строковые данные перед записью в базу обрабатывайте через функцию [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (прочитайте по ссылке про *Безопасность: набор символов по умолчанию*)

   ```
   $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $_POST['text']);
   ```

Comment: Да выкиньте вы уже наконец mysqli. Не на него надо переходить, а на PDO.

Comment: @Etki, напишите свой вариант ответа ;)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно **учить HTML.**
Потому что база данных к переводам строк никакого отношения не имеет.

А вот в HTML переводы строк, действительно, не сохраняются.

Для того, чтобы в простейшем случае сконвертировать переводы строк в соответствующие HTML теги, в РНР есть функция nl2br().

Comment: Я изменил вопрос и добавил код.

Answer (score -3):

Добавляйте в БД код html. Таким образом, у вас будут сохраняться как текст и `<br/>`, и `<p/>` и т.д.

Comment: Господа минусующие, поясните почему в БД не следует сохранять html  код?

Comment: Вот именно!Пожалуйста объясняйте.А если не нравится мой ответ, предложите свой собственный

Comment: @Shilgen: возможно, потому, что этот ответ собственно решения-то не дает. Как добавлять, какими инструментами?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я ценю ваше неумение читать (перечитайте мой первый  комментарий), ответ подходит для первой редакции вопроса, stackoverflow создан для помощи а не для выполнения чужой работы ( я про ваши вопросы "Как...?")

Comment: @Shilgen: минусы не от меня, я просто предлагаю вам идею, почему могут быть минусы.

Comment: @Shilgen: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037/181472